# How to remove ORA-01562: Failed to extend rollback segment error while updating 100 million rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

A table is having 100 million records and I need to update a column by adding 10% into the salary of each employee. when I execute update statement I am getting this error:

> ORA-01562: Failed to extend rollback segment

How can I update this column for the best performance result?

```
update employee
set salary = salary + (salary*10/100)
```

OR

```
declare  
i number(10);
limit number(10) := 100000;
begin
for i in 1 .. limit loop 
update employee 
set salary = salary + (salary*10/100) 
where rownum = i; 
limit := limit + 100000; 
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01562: failed to extend rollback segment number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162954/ora-01562-failed-to-extend-rollback-segment-number)

Comment: You could do your `UPDATE` in chunks, perhaps based on the employee's date of birth, or name.

Comment: The logic in the anonymous block is extremely broken. ROWNUM doesn't work like that. Anyway you should be joining on an ID column. Also you are enlarging the loop window with each iteration not shifting it. All of which is irrelevant, as the row-by-row processing is the wrong choice: set-based is faster.

Comment: The rollback segment exception is not a performance issue. It means you don't have a large enough Undo tablespace to handle 100 million updates. Obviously that many updates will take a long long time, but that's not what is causing the exception.

Comment: As an aside,you can just multiple a salary by 1.1 to add 10% to it `salary = salary * 1.1`; that's a few million mathematical operations saved!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Oracle version 8i or prior, as the rollback segments have been replaced with undo segments from Oracle 9i onwards.

To solve the problem, I would suggest you to check the trace file to see which rollback segment is creating the problem, then create a bigger rollback segment depending upon the update transaction size.

Comment: Nice catch with that detail. it could be that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR CUR
   IS
      SELECT ROWID, A.*
        FROM YOUR_SALARY_TABLE A;

   TYPE CUR_TYPE IS TABLE OF CUR%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   L_CUR   CUR_TYPE;

   LIM     NUMBER := 100000; -- Update chunk size
BEGIN
   OPEN CUR;

   LOOP
      FETCH CUR BULK COLLECT INTO L_CUR LIMIT LIM;

      FOR INDX IN 1 .. L_CUR.COUNT
      LOOP
         UPDATE YOUR_SALARY_TABLE S
            SET S.SALARY_COLUMN = S.SALARY_COLUMN * 2 -- Multiplying here
          WHERE ROWID = L_CUR (INDX).ROWID;
      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;

      EXIT WHEN L_CUR.COUNT < LIM;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE CUR;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach: [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330)

Information about parallel: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/usingpe.htm#i1006600)

Answer (score 0):

We can use FORALL also to achieve what is required. Hope this below snippet helps.

```
DROP TABLE test_so1
/

CREATE TABLE TEST_SO1
  ( COL1 NUMBER, COL2 VARCHAR2(100)
  )
/

--Insert values
INSERT INTO TEST_SO1
SELECT LEVEL,'AVRAJIT'||LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10000
/

--FORALL UPDATE
DECLARE
type TEST_REC
IS
  RECORD
  (
    COL1 NUMBER,
    COL2 VARCHAR2(100),
    col3 VARCHAR2(100));
type TEST_TAB
IS
  TABLE OF TEST_REC;
  LV_TAB TEST_TAB;
  CURSOR LV_CUR
  IS
    SELECT col1,col2,rowid FROM TEST_SO1;
BEGIN
  OPEN LV_CUR;
  LOOP
    FETCH LV_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO LV_TAB LIMIT 1000;
    EXIT
  WHEN LV_TAB.COUNT=0;
    FORALL I IN LV_TAB.FIRST..LV_TAB.LAST
    UPDATE TEST_SO1 SET COL2 = 'shubhojit' WHERE ROWID = lv_tab(i).col3;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```